# Saving email from Outlook into folder with Python

Tags: python, email, outlook

I'm trying to automate saving emails in our folders from outlook. I don't see a code for saving an email as .msg or any other type.

```
import win32com.client
import os
os.chdir("filepathhere")
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
accounts= win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").Session.Accounts;

Tokyo = "email from Tokyo"

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 
subject = Tokyo
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()

for msg in messages:
    if msg.subject == Tokyo:
        msgname = msg.subject
        msgname=str(msgname)
        print msgname
        message.saveasfile(msgname+".msg")
```

I get the error message:
AttributeError: .saveasfile

Comment: If you want to save the message that you're on within the loop, your last line should read `msg.saveasfile()`. Does that help? I'm not familiar with the win32com package.

Comment: I still get the error that says:
AttributeError: <unknown>.saveasfile

Comment: Where did you get that `saveasfile` from? Are you just guessing at what methods the object might provide and crossing your fingers? Look up the type in the MSDN docs.

Comment: saveasfile() is the method I've seen people use to save attachment from emails. I haven't been able to find the right command

Comment: First, where have you seen that? If you give us a link, we can check whether you're actually doing the same thing as them. Second, you're not trying to save an attachment, you're trying to save a message. Those are obviously going to be different types, so why are you assuming they'll have the same methods?

Comment: Have you tried just `SaveAs()`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-saveas-method-outlook

Comment: it says i don't currently have the right permissions to access to folder I'm trying to save in (separate issue) - but this seems to be working! my last line was msg.SaveAs(file_path)
Thanks!

Comment: @pypi34 No problem! I added it as an answer so as not to break the "answering in comments" rule.

Answer (score 4):

The below code works:

```py
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import os
import re

outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
print(inbox)
messages = inbox.items
message = messages.GetLast()
name = str(message.subject)
#to eliminate any special charecters in the name
name = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', name)+'.msg'
#to save in the current working directory
message.SaveAs(os.getcwd()+'//'+name)
```

Answer (score 2):

`SaveAsFile` is a method only to be used on attachments.

For the message itself, use simply `message.SaveAs()`.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-saveas-method-outlook

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get your code to work.
In line 20 I believe that you have an issue:

```
message.saveasfile(msgname+".msg")
```

This "message" should save the first email in the inbox, not the current msg you have in your for loop.  I believe that it is just a typo.  Anyway I think you meant to use:

```
msg.saveas(msgname+".msg")
```

Which saves a file directly to my Documents folder.  I haven't managed to get your os.chdir to save the file to a specified destination.