# How to save Emails of day from Outlook into a folder using python?

Tags: python, email

I have been looking for a way to save all emails in the outlook of a particular day or from the start of the day to the time I run my program to my local folder using python. Is there any way we can do this?

Comment: Got what i was looking for! Please refer to this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621535/saving-email-from-outlook-into-folder-with-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving email from Outlook into folder with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621535/saving-email-from-outlook-into-folder-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines, I believe, would be an excellent starting point:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(r"C:\test_msg.msg")

print msg.SenderName
print msg.SenderEmailAddress
print msg.SentOn
print msg.To
print msg.CC
print msg.BCC
print msg.Subject
print msg.Body

count_attachments = msg.Attachments.Count
if count_attachments > 0:
    for item in range(count_attachments):
        print msg.Attachments.Item(item + 1).Filename

del outlook, msg
```

*snippet of code comes from another thread see below*

Refer to [Brent Edwards's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30445067/9814037) answer for more details.

Note: If you won't use Outlook client you could do as follow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49681576/9814037

Comment: Hey, Appreciate the answer. But instead of writing the contents, is there a way we can just save the email as it is? Consider it as if we are copying an email from the inbox to our local machine.

Comment: With Python, you can save the content of the body (for instance) to a file such as a csv or whatever you want? Refer to this quick introduction: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

Comment: @RishabS Did it work ? If so could you accept the answer?

Comment: Hey, I have posted what I was looking for. It was saving the info in the email format, please refer to the link above in my answer. But thank you for the effort, appreciate it a lot.